# 'Int32 Userid()' method - The work before with LINQ but has gone to the entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

It's like I've gone from Linq to entity framework yesterday. but after I got right up in the code the different places on the page. but when I just need to log into the page so gives me problems.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Userid()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

The make mistakes when I need to find out whether the user has a session to know whether you are log in or not.

However, it is the first time I work with the EF(entity framework) but has long worked with Linq in about 2 years soon.

```
private static int Userid()
    {
        return Helper.BrugerInformation.SessionVale.SessionBrugerid();
    }

public static string UserLayOut()
        {
            var checkuser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == Userid());
            if(checkuser != null)
            {
                return "~/Views/Shared/_backendLayout.cshtml";
            }
            else
            {
                return "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
            }
        }
```

Return session info:

```
public const string BrugerId = "Brugerid";

        public class SessionVale
        {
            public static int SessionBrugerid()
            {
                string brugerid = BrugerId;
                return Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session[brugerid]);
            }
        }
```

How can I get done so that I can use the different values as I could before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a local variable, eg

```
int userid =  Userid();
var checkuser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == userid );
```

Comment: Not how delicious that you were so quick to help me with solved problem !. Many times thank you and hope you will give me a +1 for questions.

Merry Christmas.